# Trigonometric problem in triangles.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I need your help. I'm studying physics, but I have a trigonometric problem. I attached a figure where depicts the angles and the unknown $x$. The idea that I want to understand is how to express $x$ in terms of $m$, $n$, $a$ and $b$. Because the solution is $x=m\cdot\sin a + n\cdot\cos b$.

Please, show me the clues to get the solution.

[image: angles]

Comment: I think $x=\sqrt{m^2+n^2}\cdot \sin(a+b)$ is easier to see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the radius of the circle is $1$. Assuming that, realize that $\sin b=n$ and $\cos b = m$. We have that
$$x=\sin (a+b)=\sin a \cos b+\sin b \cos a=m\sin a+n\cos a$$

Comment: Thanks, I've lost a lot of time, I was blind. It works with any radius. Thank you.

Comment: The radius is not 1 and hence the left part of what you wrote is incorrect. The radius is root of $$m^2 + n^2$$. The correct solution is what Hagen Von Eitzen wrote

Comment: Actually, the radius doesn't change de solution, since $\sin b=\frac{n}{\sqrt{m^2+n^2}}$, $\cos b=\frac{m}{\sqrt{m^2+n^2}}$ and $x=\sqrt{m^2+n^2} \sin(a+b)$, which yelds the same solution.

Comment: Yes, you are right, any value for radius is replaced by the values of $m$ or $n$, and it doesn't change de solution. Anyway, there are various expressions for this case, but for the relation, only one solution. It's for SIMPLE HARMONIC MOTION case.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**$$\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-(a+b))=\frac{x}{\sqrt{(m^2+n^2)}}$$

> $$x=\left(\sin a\underbrace{\cos b}_\color{red}{\dfrac{m}{\sqrt{(m^2+n^2)}}}+\underbrace{\sin b}_\color{green}{\dfrac{n}{\sqrt{(m^2+n^2)}}}\cos a\right)\sqrt{(m^2+n^2)}$$

Answer (score 0):

The length of the thick black line can either be determined by Pythagoras of m and n or trigonometry.
The angle between the black and red line are pi/4 - a - b.
and then use cosine for that angle multiplied by the length of the black line for X .